# C exercise with sscanf

Tags: c

I'm making an exercise in C and what I want is that my programme reads the info that's in my text file:

```
548765454254684 35.5 24 productodelimpieza
548765454254685 40.0 15 productoderopa
548765454254686 20.5 50 productodecomida
548765454254687 10.0 30 productodecajas
```

And pass that information to a binary file.

The problem is that the output is the following...

```
Cantidad: 24
Codigo: 548765454254684productodelimpieza
Descripcion: productodelimpieza
Precio: 35.50

Cantidad: 15
Codigo: 548765454254685productoderopa
Descripcion: productoderopa
Precio: 40.00

Cantidad: 50
Codigo: 548765454254686productodecomida
Descripcion: productodecomida
Precio: 20.50

Cantidad: 30
Codigo: 548765454254687productodecajas
Descripcion: productodecajas
Precio: 10.00
```

The two strings print together.

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 4

typedef struct articulo {
    char cod[15];
    char desc[50];
    float precio;
    int cant;

}tarticulo;

tarticulo llenarestruct();
void mostrarArch(char nombre[]);

int main() {
    tarticulo art_aux;
    FILE* arch;
    char nombreArchivo[] = "archivoBinario.bin";
    arch = fopen(nombreArchivo, "wb");
        if (arch == NULL) {
            puts("error");
            return 1;
        }

    FILE* archtxt;
    archtxt = fopen("articulos.txt", "rt");
    if (archtxt == NULL) {
        puts("error");
        fclose(archtxt); // Cerrar el archivo binario en caso de error
        return 1;
    }

    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
        art_aux = llenarestruct(archtxt);
        fwrite(&art_aux, sizeof(art_aux), 1, arch);
    }

    fclose(arch);
    fclose(archtxt);

    mostrarArch(nombreArchivo);

}

tarticulo llenarestruct(FILE* archtxt) {
    tarticulo art1;
    char cad[256];
    fgets(cad, 256, archtxt);

    // Ajusta el formato y elimina el espacio al principio de la cadena
    sscanf(cad, "%s %f %d %s", art1.cod, &art1.precio, &art1.cant, art1.desc);
    return art1;
}

void mostrarArch(char nombre[])
{
    FILE* arch;
    tarticulo a;

    //indico q se va a leer algo del archivo bin
    arch = fopen(nombre, "rb");
    if (arch == NULL)
    {
        puts("no se puede crear el archivo.");
        return;
    }

    //leo lo que esta en el archivo bin y imprimo la info 
    fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, arch);
    while (!feof(arch))
    {
        //notar como imprimo la info de la estructura que esta en el archivo
        printf("Cantidad: %d\n", a.cant);       
        printf("Codigo: %s \n", a.cod);     
        printf("Descripcion: %s\n", a.desc);    
        printf("Precio: %.2f\n\n",a.precio);    

        fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, arch);

    }

    fclose(arch);
}
```

Help!!! Probably is something about the sscanf.

Comment: I guess that `a.cod` field is not terminayed by a `0` wkich denotes an end of string

Comment: See [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/15168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `cod` char array in each struct can only contain 15 characters, but the codes are 15 characters long, so there's no room left for the null-terminating character. As such these are not valid strings, and printing them as strings with `printf` using the `%s` format specifier invokes [undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Anything can happen when undefined behavior is invoked. In this case, based on your output, it looks like `printf` hit the end of the `cod` array and continued on into the `desc` array. This is long enough and thus is null-terminated, so the printing ended there.

The simplest solution is to provide more space for the `cod`.

```
typedef struct articulo {
    char cod[16];
    char desc[50];
    float precio;
    int cant;
} tarticulo;
```

You might also have specified that `printf` should only print 15 characters from `cod`.

```
printf("Codigo: %.15s \n", a.cod);
```

Comment: That would need to be `%.15s` to limit it to 15; without the dot, it prints a minimum of 15 characters, right justified with leading spaces if there happen to be fewer than 15 characters to print.

Comment: That may actually be desirable to align output.

Comment: Yes, and `%15.15s` might be useful, or `%-15.15s`.  You can have fun with `%20.15s` or `%15.20s` too.